# Prove or disprove that the interior and the boundary of a connected set are connected.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Prove or disprove that the interior and the boundary of a connected 
set are connected.

---

I know that if $C$ is connected then $\overline{C}$ is connected but should be the case here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the second part consider- the open intervals.

Comment: what about the second part? somebody tell me please.

Comment: This probably involves an infinitesimally tin disc that lies on the boundary. No matter how small you make such a disc, it includes some point on the set and a point on the boundary.

Comment: could not understand.will you explain please

Answer (score 11):

For the boundary as poton says open interval is a counter example.
For interior consider  union of closed disks of radius 1 centered at (-1,0) and (1,0) in the plane.

It is surely connected but its interior i.e. union of open disks is not connected

Answer (score 4):

For the first part: Let $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and the topology on $X$ is $\tau=\{X,\phi,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,d\}\}$. Let $A=\{a,b,c\}$ the set $A$ is connected but the interior of it is $\mathrm{int}(A)=\{a,b\}$ is disconnected.